# Deserialize JSON and then insert into table

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization, deserialization

I want to insert JSON string into table i deserialize json string to object list and then insert into table but not working 
My code :

My JSON data

```
{"data":[{"ID":"1","Personnel_Number":"1001","Employee_Name":"Employee 1","Password":"12345","Gender":"M","Grade":"W5","Designation":"4","SBU_ID":"1","Department":"1","Category":"1","Email_ID_Official":"","Email_ID_Personal":"","Mobile_Number":"","Current_Address":"","Permanent_Address":"","Aadhaar_No":"","DOB":"","DOJ":"","DOM":"","Marital_Status":"","Profile_Pic_Path":"http://iprofileapi.dev.app6.in/UploadedFiles/6365794593150041732018329.jpg","Remarks":"","Status":"Active","Created_By":"dbo","Created_On":"20-09-2017 19:35:13","Updated_By":"3872","Updated_Date":"09-01-2019 12:48:00"},{"ID":"2","Personnel_Number":"1002","Employee_Name":"Employee 2","Password":"12345","Gender":"M","Grade":"W5","Designation":"153","SBU_ID":"6","Department":"28","Category":"1","Email_ID_Official":"","Email_ID_Personal":"","Mobile_Number":"","Current_Address":"","Permanent_Address":"","Aadhaar_No":"","DOB":"","DOJ":"","DOM":"","Marital_Status":"","Profile_Pic_Path":"","Remarks":"","Status":"Active","Created_By":"dbo","Created_On":"20-09-2017 19:35:13","Updated_By":"4957","Updated_Date":"10-02-2018 19:06:58"},{"ID":"3","Personnel_Number":"1003","Employee_Name":"Employee 3","Password":"12345","Gender":"M","Grade":"W5","Designation":"41","SBU_ID":"1","Department":"3","Category":"1","Email_ID_Official":"","Email_ID_Personal":"","Mobile_Number":"","Current_Address":"","Permanent_Address":"","Aadhaar_No":"","DOB":"","DOJ":"","DOM":"","Marital_Status":"","Profile_Pic_Path":"","Remarks":"","Status":"Active","Created_By":"dbo","Created_On":"20-09-2017 19:35:13","Updated_By":"5482","Updated_Date":"05-10-2017 15:36:16"},{"ID":"4","Personnel_Number":"1004","Employee_Name":"Employee 4","Password":"12345","Gender":"M","Grade":"W2","Designation":"120","SBU_ID":"26","Department":"88","Category":"1","Email_ID_Official":"","Email_ID_Personal":"","Mobile_Number":"","Current_Address":"","Permanent_Address":"","Aadhaar_No":"","DOB":"","DOJ":"","DOM":"","Marital_Status":"","Profile_Pic_Path":"","Remarks":"","Status":"Active","Created_By":"dbo","Created_On":"20-09-2017 19:35:13","Updated_By":"6298","Updated_Date":"06-10-2017 13:30:20"},{"ID":"5","Personnel_Number":"1005","Employee_Name":"Employee
```

And So On......

first i make class for all items in same basis i am not posting all data because it will be too lengthy its a sample data:

```
    public class tblEmployee
            {
                public string ID { get; set; }
                public string Personnel_Number { get; set; }
                public string Employee_Name { get; set; }
                public string Password { get; set; }
            }
```

Then i create another class for list of items:

```
 public class SalesTransactions
        {
            public List<tblEmployee> transactions { get; set; }
            public int count { get; set; }
        }
```

And then i have create insert data into sql server table on button click

```
protected void btninsertjsondata_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLDBConnection1"];
            string strConnString = conString.ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            SqlCommand com;
            string data = HttpContent("https://localhost:45333/Retrive_Jsondata.aspx");
            JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            SalesTransactions table = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SalesTransactions>(data);
            conn.Open();
            com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_Iprofile_Employee select * from " + table, conn);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            int refId = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            if (refId > 0)
            {
                Response.Write("{\"response\":{\"status\":\"success\",\"msg\":\"Details Saved Successfully..\"}}");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("{\"response\":{\"status\":\"fail\",\"msg\":\"oops!! something went wrong\"}}");
            }
        }
```

While debugging my Code in `table` i am getting `Count 0` and `transactions null` that's why my sql query is not working and i am getting 'Incorrect syntax near '+'.' In `Data` i am getting my all JSON string but unable to convert into table form 
where i am doing wrong please help me should i add for loop for mapping all column and row ???

Comment: What's in your json data?

Comment: How is this supposed to work? `INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_Iprofile_Employee select * from " + table`. Think about what is happening on that line...

Comment: @gayan1991 Please check my Edited Question

Comment: @VDWWD INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_Iprofile_Employee select * from " + table it will insert my data into SQL TABLE which data comes in table

Comment: Try this `Label1.Text = table.ToString();`. What will be the value of `table` as a string. That is also happening in that line. `table` is not a database object.

Comment: @VDWWD i use but still same result and while debugging label1.Text its showing Import_Export_JsonData.insertjson+SalesTransactions  (My project name + SalesTransaction)  which i make class for list

Comment: What is the value of 'string data' and body value of request?

Comment: @ganyan thank you for your reply but i got my output as expected

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Check how your query looks like realtime in the debugger. You`re adding to your select statement an object not string with the table name.

```
foreach (var row in table.transactions)
{
      com = new SqlCommand(
      string.Format("INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_Iprofile_Employee (ID ,Personnel_Number,Employee_Name,Password )
                     VALUES ({0},{1},{2},{3});",
            row.ID, row.Personnel_Number, row.Employee_Name, row.Password),
            conn);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        int refId = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Both code examples (yours and mine) have [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) vulnerabilities.

For better readability and sustainability try to extract your DB logic in independent classes and methods first. A common way to do this is the [Repository Pattern](https://kudchikarsk.com/repository-pattern-csharp/).

For its implementation try to use a micro ORM like [Dapper](https://dapper-tutorial.net/).

This whole approach will help you out with all these time-consuming things like debugging your, testing and maintaining for your application.

Comment: later i will change my LINE QUERY into Stored Procedure But i unable to insert my data so for just checking its working or not i use query

Comment: @NitsPatel if you have like 150 stored procedures in MySql and then you want to change the db, it will be a mess.

Comment: ok i understand what you want to say i m not rude, but this is not my question you are explaining about sql injection  ??

Comment: i apply your code but on row its showing error line

Comment: should i declare row as a string variable?

Comment: @NitsPatel edited again with correct table.transactions in foreach. 

row.property1, row.property2 are pseudo named you have to put there correct properties of your class.

column1,column2 are pseudo named too, you have to put there your column names

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201300/discussion-between---and-nits-patel).